# Samsung s5p-6818 and Android 5.1 to install or uninstall failed

Tags: android

I have developed an app and made it into system app.  I compiled it into system img, but now I need to modify the app several times and want to know how it changes.

When I use the command: `adb push 'apk path' system/app/`, it doesn't work, still operating the pre apk.

Then, I use this command: `adb install 'apk path'`, the cmd window ocurs "INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTIS".

Next I tried to uninstall the pre apk: `adb uninstall 'com.mypackage'`, but it occurs "[DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]".

Now I dont know where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ok~~~~  now ，I know that the application become into system application, it is not 
be uninstall or install way to handle.